# transferring audio files via WebSocket

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, websocket

I have to send and receive an audio file via WebSocket using mobile devices. The clients are Android, IOS and WP. Do you guys have any idea how to accomplish this? I thought about encode file with base64 and send it as string, but maybe there is a better way to do this? Which WebSocket I should use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send your audio file as a sequence of binary frames. Most WebSocket libraries provide means to send and receive binary data. See [5. Data Framing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5) in [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) for details about binary frames.